# Why my node js express app not keep alive?

Tags: node.js, express, keep-alive

I have a node js app use express that get video from youtube and response to the client, I use Litespeed Server, my server is enabled `'keep-alive`', when I run my code from localhost, it works great and the response include `'Connection: Keep-Alive'` in it's header and the whole file is downloaded.

But when I deployed to the server,the response doesn't include '`Connection: Keep-Alive'` in it's header and it always stop after download 10MB. It make me stucked and feel bad about this, so anyone can give me some solution ?

This is my code to get file and response to client :

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Connection": "keep-alive","Content-Type": "video/mp4", "Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=abc.mp4"});
request(inputUrl).pipe(res);
```

Comment: Did you check the maximum allowed size on the server?

Comment: Hi @LuisEstevez, how can I check it ? I don't know much thing about server.

Comment: Hmmm... is this downloading the file from youtube `request(inputUrl)`?

Comment: @LuisEstevez Yes , the inputUrl is the source url of the youtube video.

Comment: Resolved : The root cause is in the configuration file httpd_config.xml of Litespeed Webserver have this configuration : <maxDynRespSize>10M</maxDynRespSize> , it makes the response to stop after transferring 10MB , I modified it to 1000M and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is in the configuration file httpd_config.xml of Litespeed Webserver have this configuration : maxDynRespSize 10M, it makes the response to stop after transferring 10MB , I modified it to 1000M and the issue is gone.